# PHP Includes not working the way it should

Tags: php

Hello I have a user creation form when I click the summit button it passes the data to the create user php file. I have an include in there to open a connection to the database to insert the data however the connection to the DB is not being opened. So I know the db-connect.php works because the rest of my site works.

This is what I have tried thus far and not been able to get to work:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/includes/db-config.php');
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db-connect.php'); 
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/includes/db-config.php');
include '/includes/db-config.php';
require ('/includes/db-config.php');
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php may even be something in your unknown form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several ways you can declare paths in PHP

**Parent directory**

```
 include("../includes/DB-config.php");
```

Path starts from one directory above current one.

**Current directory**

```
include("./includes/db-config.php");
```

Path starts from current directory.

**dirname(__FILE__)**

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/db-config.php");
```

This gives the absolute path of the directory your script is in.

**$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/db-config.php");
```

Gets the root of the server.

One of these examples should work, as long as your file exists on the server. Locate the includes directory and choose an option accordingly. Wish you the best.

Comment: Thank you for your time yet again I'm an idiot and had a typo in my SQL query which cause the insert to fail and threw the error.

Comment: No problem! Got to start somewhere; it happens. @ChristopherRadarSanSouci